# Access variables using an external string.[SHELL script]

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I currently have code as

```
if [[ "$FIRSTFLAG" == 1 ]] ; then
   all_comp+=("FIRST")
fi
if [[ "$SECONDFLAG" == 1 ]] ; then
   all_comp+=("SECOND")
fi
if [[ "$THIRDFLAG" == 1 ]] ; then
    all_comp+=("THIRD")
fi
```

all_comp is just an array

So, im working on a solution to reduce the repetitive code 
I know that we can use **case** here.
I wonder if there is a solution that can be done using array and for loop \
For example(I know its syntactically wrong)

```
names=("FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD")
for i in $names[@]; do
   if [[ ${i}FLAG == 1 ]]; then     <- This line is the issue
      all_comp+=("$i")
   fi
done
```

So please tell me if there is a solution for such code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *indirect expansion* by saving the constructed variable name, e.g. `iflag=${i}FLAG`, then you can use access the *indirect expansion* with `${!iflag}`, e.g.

```sh
FIRSTFLAG=1
SECONDFLAG=0
THIRDFLAG=1
all_comp=()
names=("FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD")
for i in ${names[@]}; do
   iflag=${i}FLAG
   if [[ ${!iflag} == 1 ]]; then
      all_comp+=("$i")
   fi
done
echo ${all_comp[@]} # Outputs: FIRST THIRD
```

Oh another answer, you can make use of the arithmetic expansion operator `(( ))` i.e.

```sh
FIRSTFLAG=1
SECONDFLAG=0
THIRDFLAG=1
all_comp=()
names=("FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD")
for i in ${names[@]}; do
   if (( ${i}FLAG == 1 )); then
      all_comp+=("$i")
      (( ${i}FLAG = 99 ))
   fi
done
echo ${all_comp[@]} # FIRST THIRD
echo $FIRSTFLAG # 99
echo $SECONDFLAG # 0
echo $THIRDFLAG # 99
```

Reference:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: what if I want to assign the flag value to ${i}FLAG inside the for loop for suppose ```${i}FLAG=`cat flags.properties |grep -i FIRST | cut -d "=" -f2````

Comment: I think that followup question should be asked as a new StackOverflow question, but, you could probably make use of `eval` to solve that. e.g. `eval "${i}FLAG=1"` would force `FIRSTFLAG`, `SECONDFLAG` or `THIRDFLAG` to become equal to 1.

Comment: Actually, it appears you can just go `(( ${i}FLAG=1 ))`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that. Thank you.